# How do I update the filter or sort function in a IReactiveDerivedList when using a Grouped ListView?

Tags: gridview, uwp, grouping, reactiveui

I've created a Grouped GridView/ListView in a UWP app using ReactiveUI (and Reactive extensions).  It is very easy to do and I can even pre-define a sort function and filter function for the displayed list.  Below is some code I used to separate a series of items whether they are folders or files.  They are being sorted by alphabetical order using the name.

```
       var _backingGroups = new ReactiveList<ItemGroup<ItemViewModel>>();
       _backingGroups.Add(new ItemGroup<ItemViewModel>()
        {
            Title = "Folders",
            Items = Files.CreateDerivedCollection(
               x => x,
               x => x.MimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
               (x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name)
            )
        });

        _backingGroups.Add(new ItemGroup<ItemViewModel>()
        {
            Title = "Files",
            Items = Files.CreateDerivedCollection(
                x => x,
                x => x.MimeType != "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
               (x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name)
            )
        });

        GroupedFiles = _backingGroups.CreateDerivedCollection(
            x => x,
            x => x.Count > 0,
            (x, y) => { if (x.Title == "Folders") { return -1; } else { return 1; } }
            );
```

This is great, **but what I want now is to change the sorting dynamically**.

I have tried to recreate the DerivedCollection inside the ItemGroups.  I have tried to recreate the entire DerivedCollection.  However, when I do any of that, my video card driver nearly crashes (sometimes it does)... the screen goes black and pauses for a second.  I wouldn't call that working...

What is the proper technique to update the underlying groups of a Grouped ListView without redrawing the entire thing?

Updated 11/9
I've figured out that the problem lies with trying to change the contents of multiple groups at the same time.  I simplified the overall collection to a simple `List<ItemGroup<ItemViewModel>>`.  And then I hooked up a 'sort function changed' observable to the reset parameter in the CreateDerivedCollection method.  When they both get the reset signal, the screen goes blank and the video driver has issues.  When I only set the reset parameter on ONE of the derived lists, then it works fine.  That list sorts itself and the graphics are stable.

It has something to do with how CollectionViewSource is dealing with both changes at once.  I'm still stumped though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a hacky solution to this problem.  I'm almost convinced that there's something internal to the CollectionViewSource and GridView that is at fault here.

I ended up creating an observable for the sort function changing and sticking it into the ShouldReset parameter on the first DerivedReactiveList.  THEN, I subscribe to the CollectionViewSource's View's CurrentChanged event.  There, I put a small `Task.Delay(50)` and then kick off a new observable that causes the second DerivedReactiveList.  I have to make sure the CurrentChanged event only initiates my logic from the first list changing.

In any case, it works.  I'll need to implement some kind of debounce on the sort buttons I am using though.  If I click them too fast, I get the same video driver crash as before.  Essentially, I am making both lists change at the same time and that's a no-no.